# Is there an ideal stage order in Mighty No. 9?

Tags: mighty-no-9

In Megaman and Megaman X games, there's a preferred stage order to defeat the bosses in. Each boss defeated gives you a special weapon that does extra damage against one of the other bosses.

So, you usually fight the easiest boss first, then choose the next stage based on that power, and go on through the chain.

Since Mighty No. 9 is essentially a MM clone. The game hints even say certain bosses take extra damage from certain weapons.

Which weapons are more effective against which bosses? Which is the easy Mighty No. to start off against?

Answer (score 1):

After changing some search terms I was able to find this image:

[image]

After testing this, and based on comments from other sites, it appears to be accurate.

Cryosphere makes for a good start. The stage is fairly short, and her moves are easy to predict.

Comment: I found the same path to be the one I took eventually. Side note as well, There's a third "info" option that will appear when you're on the stage select screen.  It will only appear on a stage that one of the Might No. can assist with. So once Cryos was defeated, this new "advice" option appeared for Battalion in which Cryos would offer their assistance. (This reflects in-game as well with large traps being deactivated when a Might No. assists you.